# If $M \otimes N \cong M' \otimes N$, is it true that $M \cong M'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I tried using the universal property of tensor products to show that there are mutually inverse maps from $M \times N$ to $M' \times N$, and use this to show that $M \cong M'$, but I didn't get far. I know that this is true if $N = R$, but I couldn't think of a counterexample.

Comment: It's certainly not true if $N=0$...

Comment: The module $M \times N$ has literally nothing to do with the module $M \otimes N$. However, notice that $(m,n) \mapsto m\otimes n$ is a map $|M| \times |N| \to |M \otimes N|$, where $|M|$ denotes the underlying set of $M$. (Usually people just write $M$ for this, which is a mistake.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true in general. For example, $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \cong 0 \cong 0\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ but $\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Are there certain modules and rings for which $M \otimes N \cong M' \otimes N \implies M \cong M'$, or does this rarely happen in general?

Comment: I am not aware of an example. Maybe flatness will be a factor. You should ask another question, I'd be interested to know the answer.

Comment: @SamBirns Finite dimensional vector spaces, for example, and for quite boring reasons (the dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space completely characterizes it).

Answer (score 5):

No: We have $M \otimes 0 \cong 0 \cong M' \otimes 0$ for all modules $M,M'$.

Even if $N$ is a very nice $R$-module, say free of finite rank, and non-zero, then $M \otimes N \cong M' \otimes N$ does not imply $M \cong M'$: This is because there are non-isomorphic modules $M,M'$ with $M^2 \cong M'^2$, i.e. $M \otimes R^2 \cong M' \otimes R^2$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/), take $M=A$, $M'=A^2$, $R=\mathbb{Z}$).

IF $M,M',N$ are free of finite rank and $N$ is non-zero (and $R$ is assumed to be commutative; otherwise the tensor product has no canonical module structure anyway), then the implication is true, though.